# data-role="none" not respected when calling trigger("create") in jQuery Mobile version rc2

Tags: jquery-mobile

We just updated from jquery mobile beta 2 to rc2. We had a custom button that we don't want jqm to initialize (add extra markup) so we used this:

```
<button id="buttonid" data-role="none"></button>
```

And that worked perfectly, but now with the update it is actually initializing the button. I don't see any updates in the release notes or the documentation. Am I missing something?

Markup after update:

```
<div data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
   </span>
   <button id="buttonid" data-role="none" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false"></button>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
As Phill pointed out, my problem is hard to reproduce. Could be something with my code but it seems strange that simple changing version creates the behaviour for me. Here is additional markup that I first stripped out from example:

```
<ul class="item" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li data-role="list-divider">Something</li>
<li>
    <a href="#detailPage?id=123"></a>
    <div class="block_container" data-role="none">
        <div class="block block_small">
            <button data-role="none" id="check-123" class="check" data-id="something"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="block block_small assignment">
            <button data-role="none" id="assign-123" class="assignmentoverlay"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <h3>
                Something
            </h3>
            <p>
                lorem..
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I found what the problem is. I am populating my list from javascript. At the end I'm calling   `trigger("create")`. This will enhance all the elements in my list, even those with `data-role="none`.

jsfiddle to reproduce problem - http://jsfiddle.net/V2xAX/9/

Updating title of question

**UPDATE 3**
Hopefully the last update. We got it to work by doing the following:

When calling `trigger("create")`on my list, every element will be enhanced. We don't want this.

When calling `trigger("create")`on the page element holding the jquery mobile page, only elements without `data-role="none"`will be enhanced. This is the behavior we want.

Link for testing - http://jsfiddle.net/V2xAX/16/

It would be interesting to know why this happens :)

Comment: what happens if you use input? <input type="button" value="Input type=button" data-role="none">

Comment: Same effect I'm afraid. And the value attribut is shown as the text label inside the ui-btn-text

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce what you're seeing, I get the native element look: http://jsfiddle.net/V2xAX/4/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can't get the behavior either... I actually have additional markup around my button. Added it to the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/V2xAX/5/

Comment: are you declaring any global config options? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: No, no global config. Will debug my code more tomorrow. Thanks for the help though!